# Best way to design API routes for a CRUD endpoint using express server? Single or multiple routes?

Tags: node.js, api, express, crud, endpoint

When I'm developing a CRUD `express` server API to update the database, what is the ideal way of separating the CRUD actions?

**Option #1**

Use a single route and multiple `HTTP` methods?

```
app.get    ("/api/some-api-crud-route", handler_read);
app.put    ("/api/some-api-crud-route", handler_add);
app.patch  ("/api/some-api-crud-route", handler_update);
app.delete ("/api/some-api-crud-route", handler_delete);
```

**Option #2**

Use only `GET or POST` method (depending how you wish to pass data) and a multiple routes.

```
app.post ("/api/route-save",   handler_read);
app.post ("/api/route-add",    handler_add);
app.post ("/api/route-update", handler_update);
app.post ("/api/route-delete", handler_delete);
```

How do people usually handle this? Is there a 3rd better option?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, APIs follow REST specifications (read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/REST). This will be closer to #1, where your route represents a resource and the verbs, different actions to be performed on that resource.

Answer (score 0):

Routes pointing to a single resource should be specific one with different verbs. Like you have some methods against the User resource, then you can user only one route like "/api/user" and different verbs for CRUD operations.